# Find the range of a function algebraically without using graph

Tags: functions

How to find the range of a function  $f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x - 1}}{x^2 + 4}$

In a step-by-step solution without using graphs

Thank you.

Comment: Please include your attempt to let us see where exactly you are stuck

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi Your assumption is incorrect. I tried myself for few days. After I failed in my attempt, my last resort is to ask this community for help.

Comment: neither I am the downvoter,nor have I assumed anything about you,I am just asking to include your failed attempt too,just to let us know

Comment: What the comment means is include your attempt in

Comment: @coffeemath Let's assume I had not attempt, I do not know how to solve it. Can you help me!

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Hi, Can you show me how it's done.

Comment: @tdadhul - You would be more likely to get a response if you included in your question some of the things you tried yourself for a few days.  As a clue, you probably want to avoid division by zero and taking the square root of a negative number.  You might also look at the sign and extreme values of $f(x)$

Answer (score 0):

To start off with, let's establish a domain. The square root in the numerator prohibits $x-1<0$, so the domain is $x\geq1$. With this domain, we can see that the numerator and denominator are always positive (or 0), so the out put will likewise always be positive (or 0). We now have a lower bound to our range, so we just need an upper bound. This can be found by finding the absolute maximum of the function. $f(1)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$, so the absolute maximum will be equal to the highest local maximum. This can be found be setting $f'(x)=0$.
$$f'(x)=\frac{\frac{d\sqrt{x-1}}{dx}(x^2+4)-\frac{dx^2+4}{dx}\sqrt{x-1}}{(x^2+4)^2}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x-1}(x^2+4)}-\frac{2x\sqrt{x-1}}{(x^2+4)^2}$$
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x-1}(x^2+4)}-\frac{2x\sqrt{x-1}}{(x^2+4)^2}=0$$
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x-1}}=\frac{2x\sqrt{x-1}}{x^2+4}$$
$$x^2+4=4x^2-4x$$
$$3x^2-4x-4=0$$
$$(x-2)(3x+2)=0$$
The only maximum that falls in our domain is $f(2)=\frac{1}{8}$, so this is the upperbound of our range. This means our answer is $[0,\frac{1}{8}]$

Comment: This is correct, and well written. But I am disappointed that you answered the question when the OP repeatedly refused in comments to show any work of their own. SE isn't a "do my work for me" site.

Comment: Understandable, I'll keep that in mind in the future